# how default start extensions in Incognito mode,chromium?

Tags: chromium

**Macos chromium 97.0.4692.71**
I'm developer,I want auto enable extension in incognito mode,not enter setting page,update source code to get the function,help me?

Comment: So you want to write an extension, that is automatically enabled in incognito mode without the user explicitly enabling it? I surely hope that is not possbile ...

Comment: no,not write an extension,all third extension will be enable in incognito mode,I not update where in chromium source code?

Comment: So you want to compile your own version of chromium so that all extensions are enabled by default? And you don't know where to change the chromium code?

Comment: yes,you are right,you can contact me for facebook messenger,ID:Chou Jaytl,it's more convenience